# Turn a CSS 3d Flip into a slideshow

Tags: html, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a simple card flip animation from this example: https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

I would like to turn this (or something similar to this) into a slideshow mechanic, where I don't just flip front and back, but multiple elements, together with a back and forth button.

How would this be possible without asynchronous loading the next or previous element?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbvvyp

See the example HTML element:

```
  <section class="container">
    <div id="card">
      <figure class="front">1</figure>
      <figure class="back">2</figure>
      <!--

        How To Make this a Slideshow?

      <figure class="back">3</figure>
      <figure class="back">4</figure>
      -->
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/JKNGqO

Answer (score 2):

I did it by using 3 separate CSS classes:

> - turnedLeft (turned left, -180 degrees on the Y axis)
> - turnedRight    (turned right, 180 degrees on the Y axis)
> - active (facing the user, 0 degrees on the Y axis)

and 2 functions:

> - prevSlide: adds turnedRight to the active slide, and makes the previous element active.
> - nextSlide: adds turnedLeft to the active slide, and makes the next element active.

This is dynamic, and will work for any number of elements inside the "card" div!

https://jsfiddle.net/gmsitter/vuob9bnx/

HTML:

```
  <section class="container">
    <div id="card">
      <figure class="active">1</figure>
      <figure>2</figure>
      <figure>3</figure>
      <figure>4</figure>
      <figure>5</figure>
    </div>
  </section>

<button id="previous">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS:

```
    figure {
      margin: 0px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 260px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto 40px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      -webkit-perspective: 800px;
         -moz-perspective: 800px;
           -o-perspective: 800px;
              perspective: 800px;
    }

    #card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
    }

    #card figure {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 260px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 140px;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
         -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
           -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
              backface-visibility: hidden;
      background: blue;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
         -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
           -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
              transition: transform 1s;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
           -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    #card .turnedLeft {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( -180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( -180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( -180deg );
              transform: rotateY( -180deg );
    }

    #card .turnedRight {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
    }

    #card .active {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
              transform: rotateY( 0deg );
    }
```

JS:

```
var init = function() {
    var r = 1; 
  var slides = $("#card").children();

  $('#next').click(function(){
    nextSlide();   
  });

  $('#previous').click(function(){
    prevSlide();   
  });  

  function nextSlide(){
    if(r<slides.length){
      var activeSlide = $(".active");
      activeSlide.addClass("turnedLeft");
      activeSlide.removeClass("active");
      activeSlide.next().addClass("active");
      r++
    }    
  }

  function prevSlide(){
    if(r>1){
      var activeSlide = $(".active");
      activeSlide.addClass("turnedRight");
      activeSlide.removeClass("active");
      activeSlide.prev().addClass("active");
      r--
    }   
  }

};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```